How to call an async method but end the program without waiting for the result?
I have a Lambda function deployed with the Serverless Framework. I am making a call to an async method, specifically replicate.run if that matters in the following way:
export const handler: Handler = async (
  event: {
    url: string | undefined;
    videoId: string | undefined;
    userId: string | undefined;
    apiKey: string | undefined;
  },
  context: Context
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyStructuredResultV2> => {
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
return (
      replicate
        .run(options)
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
        })
    );

That code runs until the .run() function successfully returns (or fails). How can I skip the process of awaiting the response? When I don't use the return statement, the Lambda hangs until a timeout. If I use the await keyword, it, of course, awaits.

You probably don't want the program to exit before the operation is complete, right?

But I do not want to await it's result either. It takes minutes and incurs a lot of billed compute time.

What is the actual operation and where is that operation running and will it complete on its own if your process exits?

It's a call to an AI model hosted on replicate.com, using their SDK. Sorry, just realized I also deleted the entire options object from the example: options specify a webhook endpoint to my app. When replicate completes running the model, I will receive the result as a webhook. Hence why I want to just initiate the .run() in the above code and exit right away.

First off, you can't exit your process until you're sure that the request has been fully sent.  Since this is an asynchronous operation, it may return before the networking is complete to send the request, but a short delay would probably assure that it had been sent.

Second, it depends upon how the target server is programmed.  If, for example, the target was busy and was thus programmed to put your request in a queue and then you exit your process which causes the "in-process" http request connection to get closed, it's possible that the target host would see your connection dropped and it could drop the processing of your request.  That's not super likely, but is possible - all depending upon how things are programmed.  You may just have to experiment to see what you can get away with.
